# z-index not working on cloud-zoom plugin

Tags: html, css, image, zooming, z-index

I am trying to work on an image zoom (inner-zoom) with cloud zoom plugin.
Cloud zoom has created a wrap itself for containing the images.
But at the same time, I am having another div by its side as a popup span. However, the images are always covering my popup.

Below is the code that the plugin has generated. And I have set its z-index to 1; and for another div I have set to z-index:1999. But it still didn't work at all, the images will always show on top of everything.

```
<div id="wrap" style="top:0px; z-index:1; position:relative;"></div>
```

Is there any way that I can arrange their order instead of using z-index? Thank you so much! Please give me some hints on it.

Answer (score -1):

Set z-index of `#cloud-zoom-big` div, where it is getting created run time.
You can find `#cloud-zoom-big` div in plugin's js file.

Comment: Format your answer properly, please.